# Выравнивание пунктов навигационной панели по логотипу

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как сделать, чтобы пункты навигационного меню выровнялись на одной линии с логотипом ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<header>
      <div class="container">
         <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-secondary">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/Logo.png" alt=""></a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Homepage</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About us</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
</nav>
      </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/#align-items

Comment: ваш вопрос не понятен. как именно выровнять - блоки под линию или текст? Ваш пример не работает так как нет JS и CSS бутстрапа. В любом случае, для ПК версии вы можете воспользовать `@media` и `margin-top: Npx`

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо задать одинаковую высоту и line-height.
Либо с `position: relative` и `top/bottom` поиграться.